# MongoDB alias on collection name?

Tags: mongodb, alias

Is it possible to add an alias on mongodb collection name, so the reference in the code doesn't need to be changed? Lets say I have a collection named `test-foo` and I need to change it in `testFoo`, is there a way to add an alias so the reference in code stays the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, synomyms are not supported. You could use variables:

```
var t = "test-Foo";
db.getCollection(t).find({});
```

Then your code can be more generic.